# Properly formatted text output to .txt file

Tags: c#

I'am exporting some data to a .txt file as follows:

```
String content;
String path=@"e:\coding\";
String name="test.txt";
path+=name;

System.IO.File.Delete(path);

 for (i=0;i<row-1;i++)
 {
     try
     {
         if (r[i].points.Count() > 2)
         {
             content = "Route " + (i + 1).ToString() +"      Truck_id:"+trk[i].truck_name.ToString()+   "       Max_load="+trk[i].capacity.ToString()+ "\n";
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, content + Environment.NewLine);
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, "Points     Load        Reached_AT                         Max_load" + Environment.NewLine);
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, "========================================" + Environment.NewLine);
             for (int j = 0; j < (r[i].points.Count()); j++)
             {
                 content = r[i].points[j].ToString() + "          " + c[r[i].points[j]].load.ToString() +"          "+ r[i].time_list[j].ToString()+"                               "+c[r[i].points[j]].max_load.ToString()+"\n";
                 System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, content + Environment.NewLine);
             }
             content = "Total     " + r[i].ld.ToString() + "\n";
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, content + Environment.NewLine );
             content = "Route Complete: " + r[i].reach_at.ToString();
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, content + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine);
         }
     }

     catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
     {
         break;
     }
 }
```

As expected the output I get is not properly formatted:
The spaces are causing the text to be jumbled and not arranged. My reputation does'nt allow me to post a screenshot but I guess It can be understood what is happening.

Is there way so that the text is properly formatted neatly column wise without looking jumbled.

Comment: figure out what the maximum width is for each column and pad them with spaces so they are all equal.

Comment: @nolesh: Can you give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a text, you can use tabs:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, "Points\t\tLoad\t\tReached_AT\t\tMax_load" + Environment.NewLine);
// ...
content = r[i].points[j].ToString() + "\t\t " + c[r[i].points[j]].load.ToString() +"\t\t"+ r[i].time_list[j].ToString()+"\t\t"+c[r[i].points[j]].max_load.ToString()+"\n";
```

Just play with amount of tabs (`\t` for one, `\t\t` for two, etc...). Hope it can help.

Another solution would be to use commas:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, "Points,Load,Reached_AT,Max_load" + Environment.NewLine);
```

and save to CSV-file ([comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)). Then you can import the data to Microsoft Excel or to other software.

Answer (score 0):

You can find bunch full of good information on how to format the `string` contents in the [The format item MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but for quick answer, an example for your string

```
content = "Route " + (i + 1).ToString() + "      Truck_id:" + trk[i].truck_name.ToString() + "       Max_load=" + trk[i].capacity.ToString() + "\n";
```

If we assume,
`i`  maximum   10 digits,
`Truck_name` max 45 characters
`capacity` max 10 digits

```
content = String.Format("{0,-20}{1,55}{2,20} " + Environment.NewLine, "Route " + (i + 1).ToString(), " Truck_id:" + trk[i].truck_name.ToString(), " Max_load=" + trk[i].capacity.ToString());
```